# How to display Image using repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a page to upload a photo into my database. Then when I click upload, the photo has been saved as binary format in database:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Byte[] bytes = null;

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        string filePath = Path.GetFileName(filename);

        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    }

    string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO disc_info (disc_name,menu) VALUES('" + TextBox.Text + "','" + bytes + "')", con);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I am trying to retrieve image then it is not displayed, how to display image using repeater?

Database: menu image

```
<asp:Image ID="ViewPhotoImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# GetImage(Eval("menu")) %>' Height="190px" Width="180px"/>

public string GetImage(object img)
{
    return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) img);
}
```

Comment: your image is a jpg or a png ?

Comment: @aloisdg pic extension is jpg

Comment: still i am able to show image ...plz help me for that..... if any other way to show image using repeater plz send me code ...

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may be in how you are putting the data into the database.  You may not have valid image data in the database at all.  Does that code run for you when you upload an image?  When I run it it errors out on the sql command because when you implicitly convert a byte[] into a string in c# you get "System.Byte[]"    instead of the string representation of the data.  You need to [convert that byte[] into a binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa).  That link has a bunch of ways to do it, and here's your upload code with one of those ways (**Not Recommended, see below**):

(Edited, see comment below)

```
Byte[] bytes = null;
string hex = "0";

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string filePath = Path.GetFileName(filename);

    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

    bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    hex = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
}

string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO disc_info (disc_name,menu) VALUES('" + TextBox.Text + "'," + hex + ")", con);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

You also might want to move that sql code into the if block, but maybe that's what you want, just thought i'd mention it in case.

**HOWEVER...**

I would be remiss if I did not strongly suggest that you parameterize your sql statement to avoid injection attacks.  But not only is it better for security, it makes working with the binary data much easier as there is no need to string convert.  Here's the relevant code with parameters:

```
Byte[] bytes = null;

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

    bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
}

string cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO disc_info (disc_name,menu) VALUES(@disc, @menu)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disc", TextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@menu", bytes);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Once I did that, your other code worked fine and I was able to see my test images in the repeater.  I hope that helps!

Comment: @peterjb thankx a lot sir.... but here hex doesn't exit in current context error are occurring

Comment: @pankajnath Ack sorry, I've edited the code.  When i worked up the test, i put all of your code in the if block, but then moved it back out so it would be like your original code, but i left the declaration of `hex` in the if block, so it isn't available when i used it in the sql code outside the if block.  Again, though, i strongly recommend not doing it that way.